# Facebook Pixel Reporting (Intermittment) "Invalid Purchase Value Parameter"

Tags: shopify, facebook-pixel

Our Facebook Pixel is reporting the intermittent issue "Invalid Purchase Value Parameter". More specifically commas are being sent to Facebook for values greater than 999.99 but only **some of the time**. We are using Shopify and have installed the Facebook Pixel using the built-in integration here: (Preferences > Facebook Pixel). How do I troubleshoot this intermittent issue?

Comment: I figured out the pattern but not sure what is causing it. The problem is the purchase event is being triggering on both the 'Thank You' page and the 'Order Status' page. When triggered from the 'Thank You' page the purchase value is sent successfully to Facebook but the purchase value is sent unsuccessfully (with a comma) from the 'Order Status' whenever a customer visits that page post purchase. It appears 'Order Status' page purchases are showing as $1 in Ad Manager. Not sure why the purchase event is even triggering on the 'Order Status' page. We do not have the pixel code installed twice.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Making the below change to every script in (Settings > Checkout > Additional Scripts) resolved the issue for us. No more 'Invalid Value Parameter' for (Commas) showing in Facebook or strange duplicate events.

Replace this money filter:

```
'value': {{ checkout.total_price | money_without_currency }},
```

With this math filter:

```
'value': {{ checkout.total_price | divided_by:100 }},
```